# What is the REGEX to split a sentence but excluding some specific cases

Tags: regex, scala, split

I have a text that I need to split in subsentences but if the text contains special cases such as *domain.com* or *st. moris* it gets splitted at those points too.

Here is what I got:

```
val pattern = "(?<=[.](?<![s][t][.]))"
val text = "here is an axample with cases like st. moris and google.com here. second sentence."
val list = text.split(pattern)
list.foreach(println)
```

I want this code to return

```
List(
    "here is an axample with cases like st. moris and google.com here.",
    "second sentence."
)
```

but instead it returns:

```
List(
    "here is an axample with cases like st.",
    " moris and google.",
    "com here.",
    "second sentence."
)
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Try: `(?<=\.(?<!st\.))(?=\h)`

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work

Comment: May be use `\s` instead of `\h`.  See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/NgegWh/1

Comment: It works for me `val pattern = """(?<=\.(?<!st\.))(?=\h)"""` or double escape the backslashes `val pattern = "(?<=\\.(?<!st\\.))(?=\\h)"` See https://ideone.com/gyH0Zd

Comment: actually the pattern works on the regex tool, but the scala code doesn't split the string ...

Comment: Thank you, I got it working with ```(?<=([.](?<!\\hst[.])))``` now what about domain extensions like .com or .org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split with 1+ whitespaces preceded with a dot that is not itself is preceded with `st` as a whole word, you may use

```
val pattern = """(?i)(?<=(?<!\bst)\.)\s+"""
```

Or, if the number of whitespace chars after the dot can be 0, you may implement the logic to avoid matching a `.` if it is followed with `com`, `org`, etc. as whole words:

```
val pattern = """(?i)(?<=\.(?<!\bst\.)(?!(?:com|org)\b))\s*+(?!$)"""
```

See the [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/JwP3fv/3) and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/JwP3fv/4). Details:

- `(?i)` - makes the pattern case insensitive
- `(?<=(?<!\bst)\.)` - a location immediately preceded with a dot that is not immediately preceded with a whole word `st`
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces

Or

- `(?i)` - makes the pattern case insensitive
- `(?<=\.(?<!\bst\.)(?!(?:com|org)\b))` - a location immediately preceded with a dot that is not immediately preceded with a whole word `st` and not immediately followed with `com` or `org` as whole words (add more alternatives if needed after `|`)
- `\s*+` - 0 or more whitespaces matched possessively
- `(?!$)` - not at the end of string.

See [Scala demo #1](https://ideone.com/12sg5n) ([Scala demo #2](https://ideone.com/pLPI54)):

```
val pattern = """(?i)(?<=(?<!\bst)\.)\s+"""
// val pattern = """(?i)(?<=\.(?<!\bst\.)(?!(?:com|org)\b))\s*+(?!$)""" // Pattern #2
val text = "here is an axample with cases like st. moris and google.com here. second sentence."
val list = text.split(pattern)
list.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
here is an axample with cases like st. moris and google.com here.
second sentence.
```

Comment: Great! this is what I needed. Thank you Wiktor

Comment: Now can we make this case insensitive? so it would work for St. and ST. ?

Comment: Prepend the pattern with `(?i)`

Comment: Yep, you rock Sir !

Comment: Hi Wiktor, one last question. What about multiple separators following each other? For example ```first sentence.. second sentence```, i tried with ```(?<=\.(?<!\bst(\.+))(?!(?:com|org)\b))``` but it didn't work. It splits the sentence in 3 parts : (first sentence.) then (.) then (second sentence), instead of (first sentence..) then (second sentence)

Comment: @Firas Probably, you want `(?<=\.(?!\.)(?<!\bst\.)(?!(?:com|org)\b))`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JwP3fv/5).

Answer (score -1):

Your code is returning such value because as you have mentioned in pattern you need to split when your mentioned symbol comes.
And one of the symbols among you mentioned is "." .
So after st when "." Comes it splits.
So you have two options either remove "." after st and Google or give something another symbol from pattern before "second" word and remove "." from pattern.

Comment: can you provide a code example? I cannot change the text obviously, it comes from an external source. The only thing that I control is the regex pattern.

Comment: Than you can include "st."  and ".com" in pattern

Comment: yes, how? that's my question. I know I need to include them in the regex, but all my attempts resulted in wrong outcomes. Can you show me how to include them in the regex so the code would execute correctly?

Answer (score -1):

So this one works for me, and can be expanded with different exclusions in the text

`((.+(st\.|mr\.|mrs\.))*.+?\.( |$))`

Maybe there will be some sub-matches in the group, but you should look only for full matches. Here is the regex101.com example

[image]

As you see on the right, only two matches.

To add more exclusions, you should add to the `(st\.|mr\.|mrs\.)` part string pattern which you would like to count as exclusions.

The domain names are exluded with this part: `\.( |$)`. It says, that the end of the sentence should be a dot and a space(or)end of the line.

Reply if it works in your environment.

Comment: I didn't test it in my code as I already got a response above, but I reused the ```(st\.|mr\.|mrs\.)``` which is a good idea to include, thank you!